# LLVM malloc an array of pointers

Tags: llvm

I am writing a compiler of my own language to LLVM-IR. I have defined some structure type representing an array:

```
{ i32, [ 0 x i32] }
```

Now I need to alloc a memory for a real array of pointers to these structs, i.e.

```
[{ i32, [ 0 x i32] }* x 10]
```

But to tell malloc to allocate the memory, I need a size of the pointer. How can I find it out?

P.S. I see that 8 bytes per a pointer should be OK since there doesn't exist any architecture with bigger pointers, but am looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataLayout` of an LLVM `Module` specifies the size of pointers. The `DataLayout` is bound to the architecture and the target triple what every LLVM `Module` should have.

The `DataLayout` from the `x86_64` architecture looks like this:

```
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

Edit: to explicitly set your pointer size you can add `p[n]:<size>:<abi>:<pref>` where p denotes pointers to address space [n] (this is optional and defaults to 0). Second parameter is the size of the pointer (e.g., 64 bit). In the provided `DataLayout` above the replacement rules are used (cited from [here](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout)):

> When LLVM is determining the alignment for a given type, it uses the
>   following rules:
>
> - If the type sought is an exact match for one of the specifications,    that specification is used. If no match is found, and the type sought 
>     is an integer type, then the smallest integer type that is larger
>     than the bitwidth of the sought type is used.
> - If none of the specifications are larger than the bitwidth then the largest integer type is used. For example, given the default
>     specifications above,    the i7 type will use the alignment of i8
>     (next largest) while both    i65 and i256 will use the alignment of
>     i64 (largest specified).
> - If no match is found, and the type sought is a vector type, then the    largest vector type that is smaller than the sought vector type
>     will    be used as a fall back. This happens because <128 x double>
>     can be    implemented in terms of 64 <2 x double>, for example.

Backends will recognize the pointer size and accept it (if valid).

With this said you can do the following to get the allocation size of each `Type` using the `Module`'s `DataLayout` with the LLVM C++ API:

```
Module* M = /*your current module*/;
Type* myType = /*some type*/;
unsigend size = M->getDataLayout()->getTypeAllocSize(myType); 
//size is 8 with the DataLayout defined above
```

Comment: It's not working for me since I am generating a textual representation of the LLVM-IR. Is there any way to do this in such a case?

Comment: What do you mean with textual representation? The DataLayout providet is in text form for the module. If you declair your pointers to be 8 bytes in your DL than your malloc size will always be 8 for a pointer type.

Comment: I mean I create a text file, which is then compiled to bitcode using `llvm-as`, and do not use the API.

Comment: I see. I have edited my answer. However, if you write llvm "by hand" and you are the compiler then you are the only one to decide the size of your pointer. Your are compiling for a specific architecture and have to consider the specific DataLayout of this architecute.